# Emacs/CIDER Error

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I'm trying to do some Clojure development using Emacs and `cider`, and following [this tutorial](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/emacs.html). I've gotten to the point where I need to do `M-x cider-jack-in`, which is supposed to start a `*cider-repl*` buffer, but instead gives me the error

```
error in process filter: Symbol's function definition is void: clojure-mode-variables
```

I'm running `emacs 24.3.1`, `cider-20150412.827` (out of `melpa`), `Leiningen 2.3.4`, and I get the error whether I specify `[cider/cider-repl "0.7.0"]` or `[cider/cider-repl "0.8.2"]`. I'm able to successfully run `lein run` on the project I'm trying to edit.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using an outdated version of `clojure-mode`. Update to a recent version (e.g. the latest) and everything should be fine. Btw, you should also use `[cider/cider-nrepl "0.9.0-SNAPSHOT"]` together with CIDER from MELPA.